# This is a code to make sure the number of chess pieces is within the max limit for each piece

Tags: python, boolean, chess

why does this code return the value false?
It should return false only if one of the pieces exceeds it's max total or if the king pieces are missing, a loop at the end prints the sum for each piece and none of them have exceeded the max limit. But for some reason it still returns false.....

```py
    chessboard = {
        '1h': 'bking',
        '6c': 'wqueen',
        '2g': 'bbishop',
        '5h': 'bqueen',
        '3e': 'wking',
        '4c': 'brook',
    }
    
    
    def check_validity(board):
    
        if sum(value == 'wpawn' or value == 'bpawn' for value in board.values()) > 8:
            return False
        elif sum(value == 'wknight' or value == 'bknight' or value == 'bbishop' or value == 'wbishop' or value == 'wrook' or value == 'brook' for value in board.values()) > 2:
            return False
        elif sum(value == 'wqueen' or value == 'bqueen' for value in board.values()) > 1:
            return False
        elif sum(value == 'wking' or value == 'bking' for value in board.values()) != 1:
            return False
        elif sum(value == b or value == w for value in board.values[0]) > 16:
            return False
        else:
            return True
    
    
    print(check_validity(chessboard))
    for key, values in chessboard.items():
        print(values, sum(value == values for value in chessboard.values()))
```

output:

```
False
bking 1
wqueen 1
bbishop 1
bqueen 1
wking 1
brook 1
```

Comment: `sum(value == 'wqueen' or value == 'bqueen' for value in board.values()) > 1` this is true

Comment: how so? neither bqueen nor wqueen are greater than 1, they are only equal to 1

Comment: @senluowanxiangxiaoyaozizai, because since there is one of each of them the sum is 2

Comment: huh, just thought of adding a print statement after each condition and indeed it is this line that is evaluating to True....but it also means none of these conditions are working properly.... why doesn't "or" make it *either or* being over 1 but instead is checking if their total is over 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your sums count several types of pieces, then see if the count is higher than the max of each individual one of those pieces. In your example the sum for the kings would return 2, which is higher than 1 so the function would return false. Try this:

```
def check_validity(board):
    pieces = ['wpawn', 'bpawn', 'wknight', 'bknight', 'bbishop', 'wbishop', 'wrook', 'brook', 'wqueen', 'bqueen', 'wking', 'bking']
    max_pieces = [8, 8, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
    for piece in zip(pieces, max_pieces):
        if sum(value == piece[0] for value in board.values()) > piece[1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This answered my question but why does the sum of "bking OR wking" equal the sum of "bking AND wking"? I have the program working fine now thanks to your suggestion, but I don't understand why 'or' is being treated as 'and' here...

Comment: @senluowanxiangxiaoyaozizai Because you are taking the sum of the elements whose value is either bking or wking. This is equivalent to the sum of the bking and wking elements combined.